# Run makefile with command in order

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I've the following Makefile which run all the target when you enter make in the CLI, I know that you can run the make with specific target
but is there a way to run the make with sevral of targets ?

**for example** via the cli run `module1 pack cleanup`

with this order

> 1. module1
> 2. pack
> 3. cleanup

(for this just module2 will not run) 
and I dont want to create new target for the 3 steps above
This is the make for example

```
all: module1 module2

.PHONY: module1
module1:
    @echo "run module 1"
    DIR=$(PWD)
    @echo $(DIR)

.PHONY: module2
module2:
    @echo "run module2”

pack:
    pack $(DIR)

cleanup: 
    gbt clean $(DIR)
```

Comment: Why not `make -j1 module1 pack cleanup`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - why  I need the -j1 ?

Comment: because it prevents make from running in parallel mode. Without this it could try to run the rules of your 3 targets in parallel and the order you want could not be guaranteed any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MAKECMDGOALS` for this.  Something like:

```
PACK := $(filter pack,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
CLEANUP := $(filter cleanup,$(MAKECMDGOALS))

module1: $(PACK) $(CLEANUP)
        ...

module2: $(PACK) $(CLEANUP)
        ...

pack:
        pack $(DIR)
cleanup:
        git clean $(DIR)
```

If you don't give the `pack` or `cleanup` targets on the command line then the associated variable `PACK` and `CLEANUP` will be the empty string and won't be listed as a prerequisite of `module1` or `module2` etc.

Comment: But the order of execution will not be the expected one, I guess.

Comment: Right I inverted the order here.  Do you always want the same order or do you want to choose the order on the command line?

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to run them "in order". The entire purpose of make is for it to decide what to do and in what order. A Makefile is for listing the rules and dependencies so make can work properly.

If you want command run in order, write a script.